# facebook like widget not accepting my facebook url

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-widgets

trying to get the facebook like box (the plugin on the facebook developers page)  on my website, so i can put the wall posts on the website, but when i enter the facebook url, all i get is Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using php? You may need to use url_encode('http://mysite.com/etc') on your own own link since I believe it is passed as a variable in the FB like button (could be wrong).

Comment: it is saying that on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ (don't know if it makes a differance that you have to login to view the wall in question), as i have not attepted something like this before